# How to get first Recyclerview Adapter item positon inside another Recyclerview adapter in andorid

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]How can I get the first adapter position inside another adapter to set value in SQLite Database

I want to select a value from the radio button onClick of the item and save it to SQLite database 
it's working fine but it takes onClick last position of the item

So I need First Adapter position in the inside adapter to save a proper value of radio button in SQLite Database

Globally Declare

```
int pos = 0;
```

Here is my first adapter code

```
public class CartCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartCustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        private List<Cart> moviesList;

        public CartCustomAdapter(List<Cart> moviesList) {
            this.moviesList = moviesList;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_cart_details, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }




        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


            final List<Cart> datum = moviesList;

            pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();

            Log.e("POSI1", pos + "");


            if (loginModel != null) {
                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

                hashMap.put("option_name", TextUtils.join(",", Collections.singleton(datum.get(position).getShippingOption() + "")));
                hashMap.put("weight", datum.get(position).getWeight() + "");
                hashMap.put("zip", loginModel.getResultLogin().getZip() + "");
                Log.e("Parms", hashMap + "");
                showProgressDialog();
                Call<CheckOutShippingInfoModel> checkOutShippingInfoModelCall = RetrofitHelper.createService(RetrofitHelper.Service.class).CheckOutShippingInfoModel(hashMap);
                checkOutShippingInfoModelCall.enqueue(new Callback<CheckOutShippingInfoModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<CheckOutShippingInfoModel> call, @NonNull Response<CheckOutShippingInfoModel> response) {
                        CheckOutShippingInfoModel object = response.body();
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        if (object != null && object.getError() == false) {
                            Log.e("TAG", "Shipping_Response : " + new Gson().toJson(response.body()));


                            holder.resultCheckoutShippingInfo = object.getResultCheckoutShippingInfo();
                          holder.resultCheckoutShippingInfo = object.getResultCheckoutShippingInfo();
                        holder.shippingCustomAdapter = new ShippingCustomAdapter(holder.resultCheckoutShippingInfo,
                                new ResultCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onItemClick(int position) {
                                        //Do, what you need...
                                        pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();

                                        Log.e("postion", pos + "");

                                    }
                                });
                        holder.recyclerViewShippingInfo.setAdapter(holder.shippingCustomAdapter);


                        } else {

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<CheckOutShippingInfoModel> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

                        hideProgressDialog();
                        t.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("Shipping_Response", t.getMessage() + "");
                    }
                });


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }

        private int grandTotal() {
            int totalPrice = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < moviesList.size(); i++) {
                totalPrice += moviesList.get(i).getSubtotal();
//                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            return totalPrice;


        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return moviesList.size();
        }


        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {



            RecyclerView recyclerViewShippingInfo;
            private ShippingCustomAdapter shippingCustomAdapter;
            private List<ResultCheckoutShippingInfo> resultCheckoutShippingInfo;


            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);




                recyclerViewShippingInfo = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewShippingInfo);
                recyclerViewShippingInfo.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 1));
                recyclerViewShippingInfo.setHasFixedSize(true);
                recyclerViewShippingInfo.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);



            }

        }


    }
```

Here is Another Adapter Code which inside the first adapter

```
   public class ShippingCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShippingCustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        private List<ResultCheckoutShippingInfo> moviesList;
        private RadioGroup lastCheckedRadioGroup = null;
        private int lastSelectedPosition = 0;

        boolean isSelected = false;
        int previousSelectedPosition = -1;
 ResultCallback callback;

    public ShippingCustomAdapter(List<ResultCheckoutShippingInfo> moviesList, ResultCallback callback) {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
        this.callback = callback;

    }


        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_shipping_info, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


            final List<ResultCheckoutShippingInfo> datum = moviesList;

            Log.e("POSI", pos + "--" + position + "");

            holder.shipping_name.setText(datum.get(position).getType() + "");

            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(getContext());

            holder.radio.addView(rb);

            if (cartId.equals("Standard")) {
                rb.setChecked(true);
            }
            if (cartId.equals("Economy")) {
                rb.setChecked(true);
            }
            if (cartId.equals("Free")) {
                rb.setChecked(true);
            }



        }


        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return moviesList.size();
        }

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            TextView shipping_name, shipping_price;
            RadioGroup radio;
            RadioButton radioShipping;

            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);


                shipping_name = view.findViewById(R.id.shipping_name);
                shipping_price = view.findViewById(R.id.shipping_price);
                radio = view.findViewById(R.id.price_grp);
                radio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {

                         if (lastCheckedRadioGroup != null
                            && lastCheckedRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()
                            != radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()
                            && lastCheckedRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
                        lastCheckedRadioGroup.clearCheck();
                        databaseHelper.updateShippingInfo(cartModel.get(pos).getId(), shipping_price.getText().toString() + "", ShippingCustomAdapter.this.moviesList.get(i).getTypeId() + "");
                        label_subTotal.setText("Shipping : " + shipping_value + "\n" + "Total Amount : " + mSubTotal);


                    }
                    lastCheckedRadioGroup = radioGroup;
                    callback.onItemClick(i);
                    }
                });


            }

        }


    }
```

Here is a database Query for updating value after radio button change

```
 public void updateShippingInfo(String id, String shipping, String current_option) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String sql = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + "  shipping" + " = " + "'" + shipping + "'" + ", current_option" + " = " + "'" + current_option + "'" + " WHERE " + "id" + " = '" + id + "'";
        Log.e("QUERY", sql);

        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
```

Here is ResultCheckoutShippingInfo

```
public class ResultCheckoutShippingInfo {

    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("type_id")
    @Expose
    private String typeId;
    @SerializedName("days")
    @Expose
    private String days;
    @SerializedName("price")
    @Expose
    private String price;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getTypeId() {
        return typeId;
    }

    public void setTypeId(String typeId) {
        this.typeId = typeId;
    }

    public String getDays() {
        return days;
    }

    public void setDays(String days) {
        this.days = days;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

Here I want to update database value 
shipping charges = price
current_option = TypeId
using its position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create: one `RecyclerView.Adapter` with item, that contains: photo, price, + | - buttons, delete button and radioGroup, which have dynamic radioButtons count, created using cycle by `List<ResultCheckoutShippingInfo>`.

```
public class CartCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartCustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Cart> moviesList;

    public CartCustomAdapter(List<Cart> moviesList) {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_cart_details, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }




    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        final List<Cart> datum = moviesList;

        pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();

        Log.e("POSI1", pos + "");


        if (loginModel != null) {
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

            hashMap.put("option_name", TextUtils.join(",", Collections.singleton(datum.get(position).getShippingOption() + "")));
            hashMap.put("weight", datum.get(position).getWeight() + "");
            hashMap.put("zip", loginModel.getResultLogin().getZip() + "");
            Log.e("Parms", hashMap + "");
            showProgressDialog();
            Call<CheckOutShippingInfoModel> checkOutShippingInfoModelCall = RetrofitHelper.createService(RetrofitHelper.Service.class).CheckOutShippingInfoModel(hashMap);
            checkOutShippingInfoModelCall.enqueue(new Callback<CheckOutShippingInfoModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<CheckOutShippingInfoModel> call, @NonNull Response<CheckOutShippingInfoModel> response) {
                    CheckOutShippingInfoModel object = response.body();
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    if (object != null && object.getError() == false) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "Shipping_Response : " + new Gson().toJson(response.body()));




                        holder.resultCheckoutShippingInfo = object.getResultCheckoutShippingInfo();
                        //List<String> resultCheckoutShippingInfo = new ArrayList<>();
                        //resultCheckoutShippingInfo.add("Standard");
                        //resultCheckoutShippingInfo.add("Big cost");

                        for (ResultCheckoutShippingInfo info : holder.resultCheckoutShippingInfo){
                            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
                            radioButton.setText(info.name);
                            holder.radioShippingGroup.addView(radioButton);
                            //Check, if this element of radioGroup was checked in database and set checked it in radioGroup
                            if (info.isChecked()){
                                radioButton.setChecked(true);
                            }
                        }

                        holder.radioShippingGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                                View radioButton = holder.radioShippingGroup.findViewById(checkedId);
                                int idx = holder.radioShippingGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);                              
                                Log.i("TEST", "checkedId = " + Integer.toString(idx) + "; cartPosition = " + Integer.toString(position) +  "; arraySize = " + Integer.toString(holder.resultCheckoutShippingInfo.size()));


                                databaseHelper.updateShippingInfo(
                                    datum.get(position).getCartID, 
                                    holder.resultCheckoutShippingInfo.get(idx).getPrice() + "", 
                                    holder.resultCheckoutShippingInfo.get(idx).getTypeId() + "");
                            }
                        });


                    } else {

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<CheckOutShippingInfoModel> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

                    hideProgressDialog();
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Shipping_Response", t.getMessage() + "");
                }
            });


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }

    private int grandTotal() {
        int totalPrice = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < moviesList.size(); i++) {
            totalPrice += moviesList.get(i).getSubtotal();
//                notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return totalPrice;


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesList.size();
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {



        //RecyclerView recyclerViewShippingInfo;
        //private ShippingCustomAdapter shippingCustomAdapter;
        //private List<ResultCheckoutShippingInfo> resultCheckoutShippingInfo;
        RadioGroup radioShippingGroup;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            radioShippingGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.radioShippingGroup);
            //recyclerViewShippingInfo = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewShippingInfo);
            //recyclerViewShippingInfo.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 1));
            //recyclerViewShippingInfo.setHasFixedSize(true);
            //recyclerViewShippingInfo.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);



        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201942/discussion-on-answer-by--how-to-get-first-recyclerview-adapter-item-posito).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `Listener` pattern with few `onChange` callbacks. And pass it to one adapter to another. This would be cleaner solution.